# Pandas read_csv, reuse of skipped rows

Tags: python, pandas, csv

The dataset is made out of 10 column, yet the first 6 rows are "intro data" and has only a single column

for example, the file looks like this:

```
dataset_name = data1
date= 1/1/1970
items=1000
... (for 6 lines)

# following by the data itself
column1,column2.column3.....
```

Loading a tab separated values dataset from url,
skipping first 6 row (not part of the data, but needed information)

```
data = pd.read_csv(url,skiprows=6, engine='python')
```

**Question:** 
Since the top lines are needed, 
how does one get the skipped rows back after skipping them?
(without loading the file twice....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a file-like object from `StringIO` and read from this:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import io

url = 'https://srv-file6.gofile.io/download/su2C6D/so57674146.csv'

resp = requests.get(url)
f = io.StringIO(resp.content.decode())

header = {}
for i in range(6):
    key,val = f.readline().strip().split('=')
    header[key] = val

df = pd.read_csv(f, engine='python')

print(header)
print(df)
```

csv file:

```
dataset_name = data1
date= 1/1/1970
items=1000
line_4=4
line_5=5
line_6=6
column1,column2,column3
1,2,3
10,20,30
```

Output of sample program:

```
{'dataset_name ': ' data1', 'date': ' 1/1/1970', 'items': '1000', 'line_4': '4', 'line_5': '5', 'line_6': '6'}
   column1  column2  column3
0        1        2        3
1       10       20       30
```